# How do you avoid redundant computations in multilayered python hyperparameter grid search?

Tags: python, sql, caching, computation, hyperparameters

I need to cache results to reduce computation time.

In my code, I use `foo` to calculate `y = foo(x)` for different sets of parameters `x`. In addition to different parameters `x`, I often modify `foo` too.

For example, I have one version of `foo` in Git branch `branch-1` and another version of `foo` in Git branch `branch-2`.

I’ll jump back and forth between these branches many times in a workday. I need a memorization library that caches the results of `branch-1` and `branch-2` separately if `foo` has been called with different parameters or `foo`’s source code differs between `branch-1` and `branch-2`.

In other words, I need a library with the following features:

1. Computations are saved to the cache.
2. Computations are not recomputed if they are in the cache.
3. Computations are recomputed if they are not in the cache or the code generating them has been updated.
4. Cache results are written to disk so they survive between different runs of my program.
5. Cache results for outdated code are preserved in case I revert the code with git.

Comment: you'd need to impose a **lot** more structure to make this do anything useful.  e.g, what types can parameters (and results) take, how do these computations get invalidated when the code is intentionally changed?  if parameters are more than just basic ints/floats/strings how can you compare them between runs